# Run a scheduled task on a remote XP machine from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote, scheduled-tasks

This is very similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290559/how-do-i-stop-start-a-scheduled-task-on-a-remote-computer-programatically) over at Stack Overflow:

The question and answer here works fine when trying to run a remote task on a Windows 7 machine FROM a Windows 7 machine, but when trying to run a remote task on a Windows XP machine from a Windows 7 machine only results in "Error: Access denied".

The syntax being used for a successful command on remote Windows 7 from a 7:

> schtasks /run /s computername /tn "taskname"

When this is run to execute a schedule task on a remote Windows XP machine, the result is:

> ERROR: Access is denied.

What can be done to fix this, or is there another way to run a remote scheduled task on an XP machine from Windows 7? I do have admin access to this remote workstation. There are switches available to enter a username and password to execute the task, but entering those hasn't worked either.

Comment: you can use the /V1 switch on schtasks and it should work. just found this myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the Sysinternals tool [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553), and launch whatever task directly.  If you really must trigger execution through the task scheduler, you can try launching a schtasks command with psexec.

Comment: Yep - a colleague of mine emailed me with the same resolution: psexec \\computer schtasks /run /tn "task_name"